# Application class in winforms and WPF

Tags: wpf

I am new to GUI development, i was trying to develop a sample ui application using winforms and WPF.

I found some of the code missing in WPF

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }
    }
}
```

1. Why this code is not present in WPF when the project is created
2. Why we are using Application class, what is the need of this class?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not present because in the `app.xaml` definition there is usually a `StarupURI="window1.xaml"` attribute that allow the WPF infrastructure to wire the startup code behind the scene.
Of course you can create a custom bootsrapper, you need to remove the StartupURI attribute and intercept the Application startup to create/show a window:

```
public partial class App
{
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
      var mainView = new MainView();
      mainView.Show();
      mainView.DataContext = new YourDataContext();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF uses the `Application.Xaml` and `Application.cs` to start your application.

It start your application and you can override some methods and choose how to start your application, apply come general configuration and error handling for your application

Comment: what is the use of this application class?

Comment: It start your application and you can override some methods and choose how to start your application, apply come general configuration and error handling for your application